# reCAPTCHA - error-codes: 'missing-input-response', 'missing-input-secret' when verifying user's response (missing details on POST)

Tags: node.js, express, post, recaptcha

I am setting an [invisible reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) in my web application and having trouble verifying the user's response. (even though I am passing the correct POST parameters)

I am programmatically invoking the challenge by calling `grecaptcha.execute();` on the client-side. And submitting the form afterwards (`registrationForm.submit();`) using the recaptcha callback:

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha"
  data-sitekey="SITE_KEY"
  data-callback="onSubmit"
  data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

Now after reading [*"Verifying the user's response"*](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) documentation, I figured that the response token is passed as a POST parameter to `g-recaptcha-response`:

> For web users, you can get the user’s response token in one of three ways:
>
> - g-recaptcha-response POST parameter when the user submits the form on your site
> - ...

So I am using [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) to create a POST request on the server side to the [verification endpoint](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request) with the required body data:

```js
verify(req, res, next) {
  const VERIFY_URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

  return fetch(VERIFY_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      secret:   process.env.RECAP_INVIS_SECRET_KEY,
      response: req.body['g-recaptcha-response'],
    }),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    res.locals.recaptcha = data;
    return next();
  });
}
```

But I keep getting the following response:

> {
>    success:        false,
>    error-codes: [ 'missing-input-response', 'missing-input-secret' ]
>   }

Even though I am passing the response and secret as JSON data in the POST body.

Am I doing something wrong? Regards.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Doing a bit of research and digging around the [reCaptcha Google forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/missing-input-response$20missing-input-secret%7Csort:date/recaptcha/yEPN3d9ylT8/sisDSTBFDAAJ), It seems that this endpoint only accepts the default content type; [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#didx-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded).

Which means you should **not** use JSON to send your response token and site key. Instead, send the value as how the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` defined:

> Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by '+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., '%0D%0A').
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by '&'.

Therefore, you got two ways of doing this, either by passing the POST parameters through the URL (query strings) and sending it as a POST request:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${SECRET_KEY}&response=${req.body['g-recaptcha-response']}
```

or appending the data to the body manually like so:

```js
verify(req, res, next) {
  const VERIFY_URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

  return fetch(VERIFY_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: `secret=${SECRET_KEY}&response=${req.body['g-recaptcha-response']}`,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    res.locals.recaptcha = data;
    return next();
  });
}
```

The official Google documentation can be found here:
[Recaptcha - Verifying the user's response.](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Comment: Thank you! The POST parameters solution worked for me.

Comment: Excellent. This worked for me as well. If you are using axios, this is very helpful: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: Perfect. appending the secret and response to the verify URL worked. Thank you

Comment: Even assuming that Google makes sense of this behavior (?!), There is no information in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), not even now.

Comment: The documentation shows what the API request accepts for it's POST parameters. However, only the content type is not specified which is  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from what we can figure out. I have included a link to the official Google documentation for the verify request so future users can be informed of any changes. (Thanks!)

Comment: Thank you! I do find the documentation obscure. Your explanation is clear as day - should do a PR on the docco!

Comment: This is no sense, the API returns in JSON, but the parameters NEED be in form-urlencoded... Congrats to Google...

Comment: @IsraelLinsAlbuquerque totally agree! The biggest software company in the world but even after Recaptcha v2 being online for 10 years (!) they didnt add this to the documentation, or mention it in any way... bizarre

Answer (score 3):

Extending on U-ways answer above (thanks for that), if you wanted to keep a JS object structure instead of formatting inline params, you could make use of `URLSearchParams` and `Object.entries`:

```
const recaptchaBody = {
  secret: RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
  response: recaptchaResponse,
};

// Check recaptcha validity
fetch("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  body: new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(recaptchaBody)).toString(),
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
  // If it's not a success..
  if (!data?.success) {
    // ERROR
  }
});
```

Comment: Encoding it safely is required, unless we always assume that the parameter values are url-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue with **Turnstile CloudFlare** captcha, and somehow the internet led me to this very SO page.

But the above anwsers helped me a lot and in my case this was a missing value in header

`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`